# Python graphics - drawing limit?

Tags: python-3.x, limit, draw, zelle-graphics

I've created hangman using zelle graphics in Python. Everything is working fine and dandy, but all of a sudden i can no longer draw anything on the window? I have tried everything, putting the text in other parts of the program, totally changing the coordinates and the text, and it just will not draw anything. My only answer to this problem is that there may be a limit to how much I can display on the graphics window? Can anybody confirm this?

```
from graphics import *
import random

def indexFind(word,guess):
    result = list()
    for i,x in enumerate(word):
        if x == guess:
            result.append(i)
    return result

def hangman(word, definition):
    returnStuff = {'again':0, '1st':1}

    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o',
                'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

    win = GraphWin("Hangman", 800, 550)
    win.setBackground("yellow")

    titleText = Text(Point(400,50), 'HANGMAN')
    titleText.setSize(24)
    titleText.setStyle('bold')
    titleText.draw(win)

    #Building the hangman base
    base = Line(Point(120,350),Point(230,350))
    base.draw(win)
    stand = Line(Point(175,350),Point(175,150))
    stand.draw(win)
    stand2 = Line(Point(175,150),Point(250,150))
    stand2.draw(win)
    stand3 = Line(Point(250,150),Point(250,180))
    stand3.draw(win)

    #drawing the empty lines for the word
    x1 = 150
    x2 = 180
    print(word)
    for l in range (len(word)):
        wordLine = Line(Point(x1, 420),Point(x2,420))
        wordLine.draw(win)
        x1+=40
        x2+=40

    incorrectText = Text(Point(600,300), 'Incorrect Guesses:')
    incorrectText.draw(win)

    guessCounter = 0
    textCheck = 0
    repeatCheck = 0
    invalidText = Text(Point(600,100), 'You did not enter a valid letter.')
    invalidText.setTextColor('red')
    repeatText = Text(Point(600,100), 'You already guessed this letter.')
    repeatText.setTextColor('red')
    guesses = []
    letterCount = 0
    while guessCounter < 6:
        indexes = []
        #text entry box
        textEntry = Entry(Point(600,180),10)
        textEntry.draw(win)
        guessText = Text(Point(600,150), 'Guess a letter:')
        guessText.draw(win)
        #user has to click this box to confirm the letter
        enterBox = Rectangle(Point(580,200), Point(620,220))
        enterBox.setFill('white')
        enterBox.draw(win)
        clickText = Text(Point(600,210), 'Enter')
        clickText.draw(win)
        #guessing the word
        guessWordText = Text(Point(400,250), 'Guess the word:')
        guessWordText.draw(win)
        wordEntry = Entry(Point(400,270),15)
        wordEntry.draw(win)
        #isnt drawing this 
        enterBox2 = Rectangle(Point(380,260), Point(420,280))
        enterBox2.setFill('white')
        enterBox2.draw(win)
        click2 = Text(Point(400,270), 'Enter')
        click2.draw(win)

        click = win.getMouse()
        x = click.getX()
        y = click.getY()

        if 580 < x < 620 and 200 < y < 220:
            guess = textEntry.getText().lower().strip()

            #checks if the entered letter is in the alphabet
            if guess not in alphabet:
                if repeatCheck == 1:
                    repeatText.undraw()
                    repeatCheck = 0

                if textCheck == 0:
                    invalidText.draw(win)
                    textCheck = 1

            #checks if the entered letter is not a repeat
            elif guess in guesses:
                if textCheck == 1:
                    invalidText.undraw()
                    textCheck = 0

                if repeatCheck == 0:
                    repeatText.draw(win)
                    repeatCheck = 1

            #if the entered letter is in the alphabet and is not a repeat, this code will execute   
            else:
                guesses.append(guess)

                if textCheck == 1:
                    invalidText.undraw()
                    textCheck = 0

                elif repeatCheck == 1:
                    repeatText.undraw()
                    repeatCheck = 0

                for letter in word:
                    if letter == guess:
                        indexes = indexFind(word,guess)

                if len(indexes) == 0:
                    guessCounter += 1
                    if guessCounter == 1:
                        guessText1 = Text(Point(550,320), guess)
                        guessText1.draw(win)
                        head = Circle(Point(250,200), 20)
                        head.draw(win)

                    elif guessCounter == 2:
                        guessText2 = Text(Point(570,320), guess)
                        guessText2.draw(win)
                        body = Line(Point(250,220),Point(250,270))
                        body.draw(win)

                    elif guessCounter == 3:
                        guessText3 = Text(Point(590,320), guess)
                        guessText3.draw(win)
                        rightArm = Line(Point(250,230),Point(265,265))
                        rightArm.draw(win)

                    elif guessCounter == 4:
                        guessText4 = Text(Point(610,320), guess)
                        guessText4.draw(win)
                        leftArm = Line(Point(250,230),Point(235,265))
                        leftArm.draw(win)

                    elif guessCounter == 5:
                        guessText5 = Text(Point(630,320), guess)
                        guessText5.draw(win)
                        rightLeg = Line(Point(250,270),Point(265,300))
                        rightLeg.draw(win)

                    elif guessCounter == 6:
                        guessText6 = Text(Point(650,320), guess)
                        guessText6.draw(win)
                        leftLeg = Line(Point(250,270),Point(235,300))
                        leftLeg.draw(win)

                else:
                    for item in indexes:
                        x = 165
                        x += 40* int(item)
                        if x == 165:
                            correctLetter = Text(Point(x,410), guess.upper())

                        else:
                            correctLetter = Text(Point(x,410), guess)

                        correctLetter.draw(win)
                        letterCount += 1
                        if letterCount == len(word):
                            guessCounter = 10


    if guessCounter == 10:
        victoryText = Text(Point(400,200), 'YOU WIN!')
        victoryText.setSize(18)
        victoryText.setStyle('bold')
        victoryText.setTextColor('green')
        victoryText.draw(win)

    else:
        loseText = Text(Point(400,200), 'YOU LOSE!')
        loseText.setSize(18)
        loseText.setStyle('bold')
        loseText.setTextColor('red')
        loseText.draw(win)

        wordText = Text(Point(400,220), 'The word was: ' + word.title())
        wordText.draw(win)

    #quitbox
    quitBox = Rectangle(Point(30, 500), Point(100,550))
    quitBox.setFill('green')
    quitBox.draw(win)
    quitorNah = Text(Point(60, 490), 'Quit')
    quitorNah.draw(win)

    #againbox
    quitBox = Rectangle(Point(710, 500), Point(780,550))
    quitBox.setFill('green')
    quitBox.draw(win)
    quitorNah = Text(Point(750, 490), 'Play Again')
    quitorNah.draw(win)

    #definition of word
    definitionText = Text(Point(400, 450), definition)
    definitionText.draw(win)

    click2 = win.getMouse()
    x2 = click2.getX()
    y2 = click2.getY()

    while True:
        if 30 < x2 < 100 and 500 < y2 < 550:
            returnStuff['again'] = 0
            win.close()
            break

        elif 710 < x2 < 780 and 500 < y2 < 550:
            returnStuff['again'] = 1
            win.close()
            break

    return returnStuff 

#list with various words pertaining to nanotechnology
words = ['nanotechnology', 'science', 'nanometre' , 'strength', 'chemistry',
         'small', 'molecule', 'light' , 'weight', 'technology', 'materials',
         'property', 'physics', 'engineering', 'matter', 'waterloo', 'nanobot',
         'reaction', 'structure', 'cells']

definitions = {
    'nanotechnology' : 'The field concerning objects that are between 1-100 nanometres. ',
    'science'  : 'Nanotechnology is a new field of science.',
    'nanometre': 'A nanometre is a billionth of a metre. (10^-9)',
    'strength' : 'Nano materials have higher strength than regular materials.',
    'chemistry': 'High level chemistry plays a big role in Nanoscience.',
    'small'    : 'Nano is an extremly small scale that is used in Nanotechnology.',
    'molecule' : 'Nanotechnology is researched and conducted at the molecular level.',
    'light'    : 'Nano materials give increased control of the light spectrum.',
    'weight'   : 'Nano materials have an extremly small weight.',
    'technology':'Lots of new technology is being created thanks to Nanoscience.',
    'materials': 'Nano materials have enhanced properties that are very useful.',
    'property' : 'Nano materials have enhances properties that are very useful.',
    'physics'  : 'A high understanding of physics is required to study Nanotechnology.',
    'engineering' : 'Nanotechnology has recently become a new strand of engineering.',
    'matter'   : 'The structure of matter can be manipulated and modified using Nanotechnology.',
    'waterloo' : 'Waterloo is the only university in Canada to have a specialized Nanotechnology undergraduate degree.',
    'nanobot'  : 'Nanobots are extremly small machines used in Nanotechnology to perform certain tasks.',
    'reaction' : 'Nano materials can have greater chemecial reactivity than other materials.',
    'structure': 'Nanoscience looks at the structre of molecules to find ways to manipulate them.',
    'cells'    : 'Nanotechnology is conducted at a scale much smaller than a single cell.'}



#picks a random word from the list
word = random.choice(words)

#gets the defintion of the chosen word from the dictionary of definitions for each word 
definition = definitions[word]

#this variable ensures it opens the game the first time
initialCall = 1
#stores the returnValue for the first call
returnValue = hangman(word, definition)

#sets the initialCall to 0 after first call 
if returnValue['1st']==1:
    initialCall=0

#Calls the game function again if user wishes
while initialCall == 1 or returnValue['again'] == 1:
    word = random.choice(words)
    definition = definitions[word]
    returnValue = hangman(word, definition)
```

This is where it isn't drawing anything:

```
#isnt drawing this 
            enterBox2 = Rectangle(Point(380,260), Point(420,280))
            enterBox2.setFill('white')
            enterBox2.draw(win)
            click2 = Text(Point(400,270), 'Enter')
            click2.draw(win)
```

Sorry for the huge block of code, it probably isn't necessary but thought it might help if somebody wants to run my program to try and figure out the problem.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. The white box containing the word "Enter" is drawn successfully for me.

Comment: nevermindd i figured out my problem aha i feel so silly. The coordinates were the same as the coordinates on the entry box so it was hiding behind it.